# Search Filter MongoDB Nestjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, backend

When Implementing a search filter on a document withh populated documents and array of object, How can I enable the search filter to checkout the populated document or array for the searched word?
What I have only checks through the surface fields

```
    async findAllFeedbacks(user: any, payload: FilterDto) {
            if (payload.fields) {
                const query = await this.distributionChannelsDocumentModel
                    .find({
                        [payload.fields]: {
                            $regex: `${payload.searchFilter}`,
                            $options: 'i'
                        },
                    })
                    .clone()
                    .where({ business: user.business })
                    .populate({
                        path: 'feedbackId',
                        // match: { 'feedbackId[payload.fields]': { $regex: `${payload.searchFilter}` } } 
                    })
                        
                return { query, total: query.length }
            } else {
                const query = await this.distributionChannelsDocumentModel
                    .find()
                    .clone()
                    .where({ business: user.business })
                    .populate('feedbackId')
                return { query, total: query.length }
                }
    }
```

Here is a response sample:

```
{
    "query": [
        {
            "_id": "62a8645641b312b3a04a7233",
            "feedbackId": {
                "_id": "62a8642b41b312b3a04a722a",
                "title": "Monthly Feedback test",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "title": "Rate Our Services test",
                        "subtitle": "Customer retention is our priority",
                        "type": "SMILEY"
                    }
                ],
                "thankYouMessage": "Thanks for dropping a feedback",
                "allowComment": true,
                "allowEmail": true,
                "allowFullName": false,
                "allowAttachment": false,
                "status": "Active",
                "business": "62a83f5ab4b33de7307e9cb8",
                "user": "62a83f59b4b33de7307e9cb6",
                "createdAt": "2022-06-14T10:34:19.709Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-06-14T10:34:19.709Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "user": "62a83f59b4b33de7307e9cb6",
            "distributionChannelType": [
                "email"
            ],
            "meta": [
                {
                    "sender": "string",
                    "subject": "string",
                    "positioning": "string",
                    "timing": "string",
                    "brandColor": "string"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2022-06-14T10:35:02.092Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-06-14T10:35:02.092Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "62b1c87510fae7f3a54b13b2",
            "feedbackId": {
                "_id": "62ac55d0b28630c3a8c9b940",
                "title": "Yearly Feedback",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "title": "Rate Our Services",
                        "subtitle": "We love to hear from you! How is your Jumia food experience",
                        "type": "SMILEY"
                    }
                ],
                "thankYouMessage": "Thanks for dropping a feedback",
                "allowComment": true,
                "allowEmail": true,
                "allowFullName": false,
                "allowAttachment": false,
                "status": "Active",
                "business": "62ac434542452ccb513f2241",
                "user": "62ac434542452ccb513f223f",
                "createdAt": "2022-06-17T10:22:08.863Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-06-17T10:22:08.863Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "user": "62ac434542452ccb513f223f",
            "distributionChannelType": [
                "sms"
            ],
            "meta": [
                {
                    "position": "bottom",
                    "timing": "",
                    "brandColor": "#444"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2022-06-21T13:32:37.895Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-06-21T13:32:37.895Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

In the above response, feedbackId is the populated document and questions is the array I would also want to search through when using the search  filter

Comment: You can exclude the feedbackId from the match option, like ```match: { '[payload.fields]': { $regex: `${payload.searchFilter}` } } ```. Did you try it?

Comment: I fixed it already,  I used the mongoDB aggregate  method...it's a very powerful method.

Comment: Good to hear! Maybe share your solution as an answer when you find the time. Thanks

Comment: Would do just that...thanks